# Cloning the Plutus and the Plutus-Apps repositories for Plutus Pioneer Program Cohort #3

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

In regards to the Plutus Pioneer Program Cohort #3, do I clone the Plutus and Plutus-Apps repositories using HTTPS, an SSH key, or GitHub CLI?

Answer (score 1):

use commands `git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git` and  `git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program.git`

Answer (score 0):

You can clone them however you like. My preference is always to clone everything using ssh login: `git clone git@github.com:input-output-hk/plutus`, however you wouldn't be able to push back to that URL anyways so cloning via https as the above answer suggests would be just as good.